# Postfix overwrite myhostname with custom one via main.cf

Tags: postfix

I'm using postfix. I'm trying to overwrite the config param `myhostname`, but for whatever reason it's always using the OS hostname.

The OS hostname is `linux.0fa738.com` which I don't want. I'd want it to my `domain.tld`.

My `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file is like this:

```
myhostname = domain.tld
```

A `postconf -d | grep myhostname` gives me:

```
someuser@linux:/etc/postfix$ postconf -d | grep myhostname
lmtp_lhlo_name = $myhostname
local_transport = local:$myhostname
milter_macro_daemon_name = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
myhostname = linux.0fa738.com
myorigin = $myhostname
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_proxy_ehlo = $myhostname
```

Which is all fine and dandy since this is the default config which should be overwritten by the `main.cf` file. But it's not.

Simply changing the hostname of the OS works fine, but ofc I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: There are good reasons for system to have `myhostname` equal system hostname. Do we have an XY problem here? Why you need that? What you are trying to achieve in the end? Did you want to receive mail for `domain.tld` and deliver it locally? BTW, which OS distribution do you use (their init scripts may play some role here)?

Comment: I don't want to receive mail, in fact it's a null server. This isn't a XY problem, this is a simple config issue. And I need it for obvious reasons, having name@linux.0fa738.com looks bad. Ubuntu 20.04 is the distro.

Comment: No, it doesn't look bad. This is a concrete server name. That's much better than having messages "from domain.tld" and not having clues why domain name appeared in the place where hostname must be, and where to go to solve this error. And so, why do you need an usunual config?